# Allow access to certain file only from iframe

Tags: iframe, membership

We need to provide access to a certain part of our website on another website via an iframe. Our website is static so there is no need to arrange server feeing of content via protected sessions. we have these two objectives:

1) only allow certain pages to be accessible via an iframe. There will be a link to our website on this frame - but it should not be possible for anyone to access content directly from our website

2) We need to make sure our files can only be accessed via iframes only from specific domains (which purchased the subscription).

I wonder if the above two objectives can be accomplished with minimum probability of being broken into?

Comment: <script language="Javascript"><!-- 
if (top.location == self.location) { 
  top.location = "index.html" // must be viewed in main index
}
//--></script>

Comment: I wonder if the above script securely does this?1) only allow certain pages to be accessible via an iframe. There will be a link to our website on this frame - but it should not be possible for anyone to access content directly from our website